# How to use Tiktok Research API

Tags: tiktok-api

All. Currently, I'm learning about the TikTok API. My application has just been approved, and the status has become "live in production." However, I can't test the Research API using this [Doc](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/research-api-get-started/).

Based on the steps from the [Client Access Token Management doc](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/client-access-token-management/), I need to generate the client access token using my client_key and client_secret. After obtaining the client access token and testing it with all Research API endpoints, I encountered an error:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "error": {
        "code": "scope_not_authorized",
        "message": "The user did not authorize the scope required for completing this request.",
        "log_id": "202307310836015F27C16C71256839EB9F"
    }
}
```

I read more from the [scope reference doc](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/tiktok-api-scopes/), and it mentions a scope "research.data.basic," but I'm not sure how I can use it because it's not listed in the Application scope.

I have already sent a message to TikTok support, but I haven't received any reply from them yet.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I would say that the best bet is to wait for a response from the team. Your approval has probably not been synked with the master server.